# Split line with perl depending on its format

Tags: regex, perl

I have line (parse from html) which can be in two ways (depending on the language site):

line format 1:

```
Roles: Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok), Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok)) Credits: Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok) Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok))
```

line format 2:

```
Role(s): Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok), Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok)) Credit(s): Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok) Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok))
```

I want to split this line with perl, depending on its format in:

```
Roles: Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok) Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok))
Credits: Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok) Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok))
```

or:

```
Role(s): Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok) Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok))
Credit(s): Lee Jae Ryong (Im Sang Ok) Hong Eun Hee (Mi Geum (soţia lui Sang Ok))
```

Comment: Am I missing the different way to split those two lines, or are they, in fact, identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
split /(\S*:)/, $string;
```

Comment: This work fine but. sorry for my change (see another update), but this is more better for me (space economy in number of line file create). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it (as usual, in perl). One way is by using a regex like the following:

```
(Credit.*?:) (.*?\)) (.*)
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/dt6X6wvjiq). This is essentially dividing the string into three parts, where:

- the first part `(Credit.*?:)` starts with `Credit` and ends at the first `:` character (the space immediately following the `:` is discarded)
- the second part `(.*?\))` starts just after the space immediately following the first part, and ends with the first `)` character
- the third part is simply all the rest of the string

---

With your updated question it's even easier:

```
(Role.*?) (Credit.*)
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/Io5IiKsMIe):

Comment: OK, Thanks but if Credits is not first string in line? (see me update)

Comment: do a similar thing with the new line structure, something like `(Role.*?:) (.*?), (.*?\)) (Credit.*?:) (.*?\)) (.*)`: see it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/xHqz9mYP8I). However, be careful: if the line structure gets far too complex, you might need a parser.

Comment: This work fine but, sorry for my change (see another update), but this is more better for me (space economy in number of line file create). Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your changes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a 0-width look-ahead (`(?=...)` below)

```
split /(?=Credit[(]?s[)]?:)/
```

This is an easier regex than what it could be. In exchange for simplicity, you include more cases than you might think. It allows `Credit(s:` or `Credits):`, assuming you're not likely going see to those cases in your data that you need to distinguish them. Then again, you might just want to included them, not wanting to rule out lines for containing small typos.

A more complete and complex specification would be:

```
split /(?=Credit(?:s|[(]s[)]):)/
```

which works too.

- Keep in mind that any character that falls outside of the look-ahead grouping will be removed from one of the resulting chunks. So if you just want to break *at* a pattern, all the pattern characters will need to fall inside of the lookahead.

Comment: `\(` is better than `[(]` in my opinion.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström, I could have even done (in Perl) `(?:s|\Q(s)\E)` which I find in some ways more readable than either--but more likely confusing to somebody who hasn't seen the regex quote operator. I think it's all a tradeoff. I find that I can miss the single slash before a paren easier than I can miss the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well. Of course, additional colons may mess things up.

```
s/\s(\S+:)/ \n$1/;
```

This will just add a newline, so that a print works. If you want, you can split the string on newline, `split /\n/, $string` if you want it into an array.